# Iterate through ALL values in a collection before returning true or false

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, lodash

I was wondering if there's more "functional" way to do this. Meaning, rather than having to do something like this:

```
let flag = true;
[1, 2, 3].forEach(n => if (n > 2) flag = false);
return flag;
```

I'm looking for something closer to this:

```
return [1, 2, 3].overEvery(n => n > 2);
```

The closest solution I've found is the `Array.prototype.every` function, but it terminates once it returns false, without iterating through the rest of the values in the collection.

Reason why I don't want to terminate is because I want to iterate through ALL fields in a form to display all the form errors before returning true or false in the form's onsubmit handler.

Comment: `Array.prototype.forEach(function(item) { /* each Array item available here as item */ })`

Comment: In addition to @connexo's advice, `Array.prototype.reduce()` may be an option.

Comment: @ChrisRiebschlager `every()` returns immediately on the first false value.

Comment: It would help if you explained what you want the return value to look like. Do you want an array of booleans? If so, simple: `[1, 2, 3].map(n => n > 2)` if not, what?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), which will return the elements that failed the validation if you return true for the elements that should fail.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

```js
function a()
{
  var flag = true;
  [1, 2, 3].forEach(function(value) { if(value > 2) flag = false; });
  return flag;
}

console.log(a());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a new prototype function that is like every but checks all the records:

```
if (!Array.prototype.everyCheckAll) {
  Array.prototype.everyCheckAll = function(callbackfn, thisArg) {
    'use strict';
    var T, k;

    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError('this is null or not defined');
    }

    // 1. Let O be the result of calling ToObject passing the this 
    //    value as the argument.
    var O = Object(this);

    // 2. Let lenValue be the result of calling the Get internal method
    //    of O with the argument "length".
    // 3. Let len be ToUint32(lenValue).
    var len = O.length >>> 0;

    // 4. If IsCallable(callbackfn) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
    if (typeof callbackfn !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError();
    }

    // 5. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let T be undefined.
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
      T = thisArg;
    }

    // 6. Let k be 0.
    k = 0;

    // 7. Repeat, while k < len
    var oneFalse = false;
    while (k < len) {

      var kValue;

      // a. Let Pk be ToString(k).
      //   This is implicit for LHS operands of the in operator
      // b. Let kPresent be the result of calling the HasProperty internal 
      //    method of O with argument Pk.
      //   This step can be combined with c
      // c. If kPresent is true, then
      if (k in O) {

        // i. Let kValue be the result of calling the Get internal method
        //    of O with argument Pk.
        kValue = O[k];

        // ii. Let testResult be the result of calling the Call internal method
        //     of callbackfn with T as the this value and argument list 
        //     containing kValue, k, and O.
        var testResult = callbackfn.call(T, kValue, k, O);

        // iii. If ToBoolean(testResult) is false, return false.
        if (!testResult) {
          oneFalse = true;
        }
      }
      k++;
    }
    return !oneFalse;
  };
}

function gt2(element, index, array) {
  return element > 2;
}
document.write([1,2,3].everyCheckAll(gt2));   // false
document.write([4,5,6].everyCheckAll(gt2));   // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array#every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), and check that every number is not greater than 2. Another advantage of Array#every is that whenever the callback returns `false`, the iteration stops, and the result is returned.

```js
const flag = [1, 2, 3].every((n) => n <= 2);

console.log(flag);
```